# How to delete specific lines from a txt file

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a Bash script that writes data into a log file, then from that I take out stuff I want using the `sed` command. That gives me a file `data.txt`. What I want to know is how I go about deleting specific line inside that `data.txt` file.

For example:

```
123
456
789
```

I want to remove the 2nd line, containing `456` so that I only have

```
123

789
```

I tried with `sed '2d' data.txt` but it doesn't work.

I use this command to create `data.txt` from `log.log`:

```
sed -nE '1s/.{1}(.{2}).*/\1/p;' log.log >> data.txt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this. This should work.

```
sed -i '2d' data.txt
```

You have to add `-i` flag with sed command unless you are redirecting your output to a new file. If you don't add the `-i` flag, sed will print the pattern space to STDOUT and will not make any changes to the original file.

**Automatic backup option**

It is quite dangerous to modify a file without taking a proper backup. So sed has its native method to backup a file before editing which is `-i.bak` option.

So in the above example if we use the backup option, the command would be.

```
sed -i.bak '2d' data.txt
```

So it will remove the first line from the file data.txt and will also make a backup copy of the original file with `.bak` extension.

Comment: Your answer worked like a charm just what i was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: @pa4080 Added :)

Answer (score 7):

You know, besides specifying by line number, you can also do it by matching the content of the line, if that's more useful (which sounds like it might):

```
sed -i '/^456$/d' data.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR!=2{ print }' input-file > output-file
```

That could be read as: if the number of record is not equal to 2 then print the record (line). If you want to delete the second and the third line:

```
awk 'NR!=2 && NR!=3 { print }' input-file
```

---

If you want to have an empty line as it is shown into the question, the `sed` command should look as this:

```
 sed '2 s/^.*$//' input-file
```

The first character `2` is the number of the line, followed by the command `s`, that will substitute all characters `.*` from the beginning `^` to the end `$` of the line with empty string `//`. In this case the beginning and the end characters could be omitted.

Example:

```
$ cat input-file
123
456
789
654

$ sed '2,3 s/.*//' input-file
123


654
```

Answer (score 3):

This command will delete lines 2-4 and 6

```
sed -e '2,4d;6d' file
```

Comment: 'sed: -e expression #1, char 3: missing command' i get this error, i use only sed -e '2,3' file

Comment: @Insanebench420, this works for me, also the example from your question `sed '2d'` works. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: you cannot use the command as you did (sed -e '2,3' ) you should have 'd' after the line numbers.  
If you want to specify a range 2-34  use  '2,34d'    
If you want to just delete lines 2 and 34  use '2d,34d'

Comment: @Petr that should probably be `2d;34d` (not a comma).

Comment: @JoL Sorry you were right :)  I'm not able to edit it now.